# What kind of Matrix Inverse formula does Wolfram Alpha use?

Tags: matrices, inverse

So normally the formula to calculate the inverse of a 3x3 matrix is to transpose the matrix and calculate its minors' determinants then switch the sign for every second element and multiply each element with 1/det of the original matrix.
As seen on the image attached, Wolfram uses another approach, that totally works,but I can't really figure out the rules in it. It yields the determinants correctly therefore no sign switches are required, so I figure it combines the two steps somehow? But how to come up with this formula?
Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: This probably belongs in the Mathematica Stack Exchange.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: It seems as though the $2 \times 2$ determinants are being rewritten as 
$$
-\begin{vmatrix} a&b\\c&d \end{vmatrix} = 
\begin{vmatrix} b&a\\d&c \end{vmatrix}
$$
in order to "hide" the minus sign

Comment: I disagree with the close-vote: the question is asking about a **formula for determinants,** and why it's a correct formula. The fact that the OP discovered the formula by using a piece of software doesn't make it a software question any more than the rest of the MSE questions are "keyboard" questions because we use a keyboard to type them!

Comment: Yes, if you replace "Wolfram|Alpha" with "some source", then it has nothing to do with MMA.

Comment: I might quibble your description of using the adjugate of $A$ as the “normal” way to compute an inverse. That’s only one of several.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the second entry of the first row of that matrix. In the classical Cramer's Rule approach you describe, that would be the cofactor for the row-2/column-1 entry of $A$, i.e., the determinant of the matrix gotten by deleting the 2nd row and first column, i.e.
$$
\det \pmatrix{a_{12} & a_{13} \\ a_{32} & a_{33}}
$$
which would then be multiplied by $-1$. But in the formula above, the two columns of the matrix are swapped, which achieves the multiplication by $-1$.